# Rubocop. Align the elements of a hash literal if they span more than one line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubocop

I have some code

```
# Filters
filter :name
filter :email
filter :organization_status, label: 'Status'
filter :subscriptions_subscription_status_id,
       as: :select,
       label: 'Subscription Status',
  collection: proc do
    Organization
      .includes(subscriptions: [:subscription_status])
      .map(&:subscriptions)
      .flatten
      .map(&:subscription_status)
      .uniq
  end
```

Rubocop says: Align the elements of a hash literal if they span more than one line.

```
collection: proc do
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

What can I do with it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I align :s and wrap the sections in

```
# rubocop:disable AlignHash
# rubocop:enable AlignHash
```

(cf https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop#disabling-cops-within-source-code)

With your code:

```
  # Filters
  filter :name
  filter :email
  filter :organization_status, label: 'Status'
  # rubocop:disable AlignHash
  filter :subscriptions_subscription_status_id,
         as: :select,
      label: 'Subscription Status',
 collection: proc do
   Organization
     .includes(subscriptions: [:subscription_status])
     .map(&:subscriptions)
     .flatten
     .map(&:subscription_status)
     .uniq
 end
  # rubocop:enable AlignHash
```

Comment: What does cf: mean?

Comment: I intended it as something like "see also"
though https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cf. suggests it should be for something in opposition or contrast. Oops.

Answer (score 2):

In your `.rubocop.yml`, add:

```
Style/AlignHash:
  Enabled: false
```

Comment: There is a colon missing in the first line. It should be `Style/AlignHash:`, but I cant edit because it's only a 1 character change.

Answer (score 0):

You can also disable it in your `.rubocop.yml` [configuration](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop#configuration):

```
Style/Encoding:
  Enabled: false
```

Answer (score 0):

In RubyMine or IntelliJ, If you follow the solution suggested by the IDE, that fixes it. Basically the IDE aligns the code for you.